# HTTPListenerContext responding to wrong client

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, f#

I've run into a very strange scenario where a server application that I built using HTTP invariably begins to respond incorrectly to client requests. The server is a simple program that sits over top of a database and allows for querying of that database through the sending of serialized objects from a query/request hierarchy.

I use a simple reusable HTTP server written in F# using a mailbox processor to asynchronously receive and service requests:

```ml
type public HttpAgent (port:int, handler:System.Action<HttpListenerContext>) = 
    let tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
    let processorBody (mailbox: MailboxProcessor<HttpListenerContext>) =         
        async {
            while true do
                let! context = mailbox.Receive()
                Async.Start(async { handler.Invoke(context) } )
        }

    let agent = new MailboxProcessor<HttpListenerContext>(processorBody, tokenSource.Token)

    member public x.Start () = // Starts the server listening on the specified port
        agent.Start()

        let server = async {
            use listener = new HttpListener()
            listener.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("http://*:{0}/", port))
            listener.Start()
            while true do
                let! context = listener.AsyncGetContext()
                agent.Post(context)
        }
        do Async.Start(server, cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token)

    member public x.Stop () = // Stops the Agent server
        tokenSource.Cancel()
```

As you can see, all you have to do with this type in order to run a server is supply an Action to be invoked for each request context received asynchronously by the mailbox.

The actual server that sits over top of the database looks something like this:

```
Func<QueryRequest, QueryResponse> tryQueryLookup = (request) => {
    if (request is RequestTypeA) {
        // attempt to retrieve from database
    } else if (request is RequestTypeB) {
        // attempt to retreive from database
    }

    // ... etc

    if (querySuccessful) {
        return new QueryResponse(databaseResults);
    } else {
        return new QueryResponse("Error");
    }
}

Action<HttpListenerContext> requestParser = (context) => {
    Action<QueryResponse> writeResponse = (response) => {
        try {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream)) {
                streamWriter.Write(response.ToXml());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // write error message to event log
        }   
    };

    try {
        QueryRequest request = null;
        string requestBytes = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        request = requestBytes.FromXml<QueryRequest>();
        writeResponse(tryQueryLookup(request));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        writeResponse(new QueryResponse("Error"));
    }
};

m_HttpAgent = new HttpAgent(port, requestParser);
m_HttpAgent.Start()
```

This service has been running just fine in our development environment for a couple weeks now, however today I hit an error where a request returned a response that had no relevance to it whatsoever - it could only have come from a different request to the server as the request types are completely different.

I have set up a test console application that starts a different thread for each query type and infinitely makes requests to the service. Thousands of these return successfully but eventually one will always receive a message from the server that was generated in response to a request type from one of the other threads. Occasionally, the server seems to go into a faulted state in which all requests will return messages corresponding to crossed types.

I'm wondering if there is some obvious threading issue that I am missing or behavior of the HTTPListenerContext that I am unaware of as the code seems to keep each HTTPListenerContext isolated through the use of closure inside the requestParser